# JDeveloper 12c doesnt show ADF mobile extension

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I am newbie in java programming world. I want to try ADF mobile. After reading some post saying upgrade or get latest JDeveloper, I decide to get JDeveloper12c from oracle website.

My problem is, my JDeveloper 12c does not show any extension ADF mobile even though I followed the check update instruction.

I have tried downloading adf mobile zip file but it does not support JDeveloper 12c. I do not know what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the version of JDev that *does* support ADF Mobile: [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/jdev11124download-1970562.html).
You may find the [main JDev page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) useful.
As well as my link [aggregations](https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/Home).

Answer (score 2):

ADF mobile is not yet to released with 12 c . it is still on JDev version 11.1.2.4

Edit : You can now use Jdev 12.1.3 for ADF Mobile development(  Oracle Mobile Application Framework).

Sample URL : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_app/tut_jdev_maf_app.html

Answer (score 2):

ADF Mobile has been replaced with Oracle MAF - a newer version that has all that was in ADF Mobile and much more.
Get JDeveloper 12.1.3 and use the MAF extension.