# How to upgrade JDeveloper11 to 12c?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have downloaded Oracle JDeveloper 11.1.1.7 (`jdevstudio11117install.exe`) for developing `ADF/MAF Mobile application`, I want to upgrade the JDeveloper version to latest.

It is possible to upgrade/update the latest version? or Should I need to download latest freshly. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to download a fresh copy of JDeveloper 12c.

JDeveloper 11.1.1.* has a wizard for updates, as shown on the image

[image]

but you can see that is stated that it can apply updates only for JDeveloper 11g (which probably means that it cannot automatically upgrade to 12c).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply., The JDeveloper is huge it's around 1.24 GB and I have seen it contains all the modules of ADF. Is there any specific version for ADF Mobile development alone?

Comment: okay., fine.!! Can you please provide me a link to download latest JDeveloper? And also please let me know, whether it works for ADF as well as MAF application development.

Comment: If you google "Download JDeveloper 12c" you can get the link from the official Oracle repository. And yes, it works both ADF and MAF development.

Comment: I'm going to try following, Oracle JDeveloper 12c (12.1.3.0.0) (Build 140521.1008)Installations : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html . This is fine?

Answer (score 2):

- You need to download JDeveloper 12.1.3 [from here.](http://oracle.com/jdev)
- Then install it into a new directory.
- Then use the `help->check for update` to get your **Oracle Mobile
  Application Framework** extension to enable you to do mobile
  development.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have seen MAF but where I could get ADF (Application Development Framework) Extension? And In another SO ques I have seen that ADF is not available on 12.1.3, It is still under development. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053659/jdeveloper-12c-doesnt-show-adf-mobile-extension . Is it?

Comment: ADF Mobile has been replaced with Oracle MAF - a newer version that has all that was in ADF Mobile and much more.
Get JDeveloper 12.1.3 and use the MAF extension.

Comment: Thanks, the reason to use ADF is because of license. I gone through the blog-spot and knew, ADF license is came along with Oracle WebLogic. But when we go for MAF, we need to by separate license for MAF. Can you please share the details regarding license?

Comment: All JDeveloper version come with ADF, when you want to develop MAF apps you just need to get the extension. More info abount licensing: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3595029?start=0&tstart=0